# Can't use crypto in NPM dependency in Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm building an Electron app (with Ionic) to digitally sign PDFs with p12 certificates using node-signpdf (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-signpdf). I've had problems which I solved by using `require ('electron').remote` for example for `fs`.

I've also installed the same node version in my OS (MacOS Catalina) as the same one that electron is using (Node v12.4.0).

The problem is that one of the NPM dependencies uses crypto and it shows as undefined with the next error:

```
HomePage.html:39 ERROR TypeError: _crypto.randomBytes is not a function
    at Object.ctx.seedFileSync (prng.js:340)
    at _reseedSync (prng.js:210)
    at Object.ctx.generateSync (prng.js:163)
    at Object.ctx.generate (prng.js:80)
    at Object.ctx.getBytes (random.js:92)
    at _modPow (rsa.js:431)
    at Object.push../node_modules/node-forge/lib/rsa.js.pki.rsa.encrypt (rsa.js:501)
    at Object.key.sign (rsa.js:1245)
    at addSignerInfos (pkcs7.js:534)
    at Object.sign (pkcs7.js:377)
```

What I can see is that `node-signpdf` uses `node-forge` as a dependency, and `node-forge` loads crypto inside `prng.js` this way:

```
var _crypto = null;
if(forge.util.isNodejs && !forge.options.usePureJavaScript &&
  !process.versions['node-webkit']) {
  _crypto = require('crypto');
}
```

I've tried changing that part of the code to use crypto-js or browserfy-crypto (this last one doesn't even build and hasn't been updated in years), but I keep getting the error shown above.

**EDIT 1**:
This is how I'm implementing the signature in my service:

```
public signFile(pathToFile: string, pathToCert: string): void {
const fs = (<any>window).require('fs');

let certBuffer = fs.readFileSync(pathToCert);
let fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(pathToFile);

fileBuffer = plainAddPlaceholder({
  pdfBuffer: fileBuffer,
  reason: 'I have reviewed it.',
  signatureLength: 1612,
});
const signedPdf = signer.sign(fileBuffer, certBuffer, {passphrase: 'qwertyui'});
}
```

The code adds the placeholder to add the signature, the problem comes in `signer.sign`

**EDIT 2**:

When I run the app if I type in console: `require ('crypto')` I see the methods, so it looks like it's loaded in the global scope,  the problem seems to be in the NPM dependency of `node-forge`.

**EDIT 3**:

I've changed `require('crypto')` to `window.require('crypto')` and started working. But I think I'll have to make postinstall script to modify it.

Is there a better way?

-

How can I make this crypto thing work? I ran out of ideas. Maybe you can spare some?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `_crypto = require('browserify-aes');` ?

Comment: @GrafiCode I'll test that now. Thank you.

Comment: Getting this error now @GrafiCode, seems it didn't work:

```ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/someuser/work/repos/btn/pdf-signer-electron/node_modules/cipher-base'
ERROR in ./node_modules/hash-base/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/someuser/work/repos/btn/pdf-signer-electron/node_modules/hash-base'```

Comment: did you try to manually install `npm i browserify-aes`?

Comment: Yes I did (`npm install browserfy-aes --save`), also I found something else which i'll add to my question as "EDIT 2"

Comment: I changed the code from `require('crypto')` to `window.require('crypto')` and it started working! Now I have a different error related to inside checks, not code. But if I keep this, i'll have to make a postinstall script to modify it. So i'm still open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you enabled nodeIntegration ?

Comment: Yes @Seblor I have `nodeIntegration` enabled when I create `BrowserWindow`.